# UIButton not clickable while returning to one view from second view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an app. I assume two of the views have a problem. The first view has three buttons arranged one below the other. Clicking any of the three will take us to the second view with 3 tableview cells.

The problem is, if we go to the second view and come back to the first, the buttons in the first view are not clickable. I am attaching the screens of two views.

View 1: There are 3 buttons.
[image: View 1: Three buttons]

View 2: These are table view cells.
[image: View 2: Three table view cells]

Note: The table view cells are clickable. We go back to the first view by pressing a close button. in the top left corner of the second view.

**Problem in a nutshell: If we go to view 2, click the 'X' close button, the three buttons in view 1, that is fb, G+ and Email are not clickable. **

Here is the code for the three buttons in the first view.

```
@IBAction func firstBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let bounds = self.firstBtn.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
        self.firstBtn.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - 20, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + 20, height: bounds.size.height)
        self.firstBtn.isEnabled = false
    }, completion: nil)

    goaltype = "Conversion"

    UserGoal()

}

@IBAction func secondBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let boundss = self.secondBtn.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
        self.secondBtn.bounds = CGRect(x: boundss.origin.x - 20, y: boundss.origin.y, width: boundss.size.width + 20, height: boundss.size.height)
        self.secondBtn.isEnabled = false
    }, completion: nil)

    goaltype = "Engagement"

    UserGoal()

}

@IBAction func thirdBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let bounds3 = self.thirdBtn.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
        self.thirdBtn.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds3.origin.x - 20, y: bounds3.origin.y, width: bounds3.size.width + 20, height: bounds3.size.height)
        self.thirdBtn.isEnabled = false
    }, completion: nil)


    goaltype = "Storytelling"
    UserGoal()

}
```

There is a small animation for the second view table view cell.

Edit 1: When I tried adding isEnabled = true, the button was clickable. However, due to animation, it keeps expanding on each click. See the pic:

[image: Expanded pic]

How do you make the buttons clickable?

Comment: Try this , In your first view controller set the user interaction of the  button TRUE in view will appear method. May be it can help.

Comment: How you navigating between these two view??

Comment: First to second- we perform a segue. From second to first, dismiss view controller

Comment: Why are you setting `isEnabled = false` for all the buttons? Enable it when coming back to the first view

Comment: Remove this line -> `self.thirdBtn.isEnabled = false` and try

Comment: set :
FirstBtn.isEnabled = true
SecondBtn.isEnabled = true
ThirdBtn.isEnabled = true

Comment: When this was added, the buttons were expanding horizontally when it was clicked.

Comment: Actually, we have an animation for the button as you can see in the code. So for each click, the button is expanding horizontally. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BizDev when you are adding  the code then the button are working or not??? Firstly tell this

Comment: Button is working, but it is expanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting `isEnabled = false` for all the buttons. Enable it when coming back to the first view

```
self.firstBtn.isEnabled = true
self.secondBtn.isEnabled = true
self.thirdBtn.isEnabled = true
```

For Disabling buttons only at the time of animation, enable it in the completion block

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
            self.thirdBtn.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds3.origin.x - 20, y: bounds3.origin.y, width: bounds3.size.width + 20, height: bounds3.size.height)
            self.thirdBtn.isEnabled = false
        }) { (_ isCompleted) in
            self.thirdBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
```

Similarly do it for both `firstBtn` & `secondBtn` animations

Comment: When this was added, the buttons were expanding horizontally when it was clicked. Actually, we have an animation for the button as you can see in the code. So for each click, the button is expanding horizontally. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want disable button at the time of anumation, that is OK. but you can enable it at the completion block of the animation.

Comment: Just trying that :)

Comment: Button is working. but the button is still expanding

Comment: If you dont want expanding, do not add +20 in the width for animation. use `bounds3.size.width` instead of `bounds3.size.width + 20`

Comment: Happy coding :)